# International Database for Zip/Postal Code to city/state|region/country?

Tags: database, zipcode, postal-code

Does anyone know of an *international* zipcode/postal code to city, state or region and country database? Free would be nice, but that seems unlikely.

(There are several questions regarding domestic US zipcodes, but I'd like to include the UK, Germany and a few other countries).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David,

No free databases, no.  There are a number of resellers of national data files, such as the UPU (www.upu.int).  I also maintain a database of this data myself - see http://www.grcdi.nl/settlements.htm

Note: postal codes are not there for the same reasons as other administrative districts, such as states, and the borders of their boundaries often don't correspond, so direct matches between postal codes and administrative regions is only possible in some countries.

Get back to me via my site if you need more information.

Comment: thanks for the link and the information.